Get-AzureRmContext lists an unknown tenant with a known subscription
I do:
Get-AzureRmContext -ListAvailable
This lists 4 Azure environments. 3 of which have a known TenantID and known subsciption id. 1 has an unknown TenantID and a known subscription id....
When I go to my Azure portal. I also see 4 tenants. 3 exactly as the output from  Get-AzureRmContext -ListAvailable and 1 with a different tenantID but with the subscription id from that output.
Weird, right?
So how do I select that weird Tenant/Subscription? Or maybe better, how do I fix the wrong output from  Get-AzureRmContext -ListAvailable ?
Edit:
I am trying to run my deployment script. This was always working, but now fails. It seems that it cannot select the right subscription. After trying to select the right subsciption id, my script tells me that my credentials are expired and need to run Connect-AzureRmAccount. When I do, I can login correctly but the output is the wrong subscription. So I then use  Select-AzureRmSubscription to select the right Subscription (the one with the strange tenant) but then I end up in a loop where my script tells me that my credentials are expired. When I dont Select the subscription, it tells me that my resource group cannot be found (makes sense when it is not on the right subsciption).


Get-AzureRmContext lists an unknown tenant with a known subscription:

The above error occurs when there is a mismatch in the contexts stored in a PowerShell console environment.
To resolve this, you need to make sure that all the logged account contexts should be removed and try logging it with the Connect-AzureRmAccount command by selecting a specific subscription.
Firstly, I tried connecting to Azure Account with user interaction as shown below. But the retrieved subscription is not the one which I wanted to use.

Now I have executed the below command to select the specific subscription.
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "xxxx" -TenantId "xxxx"


If still the issue persists, remove the azure account context from the PowerShell environment and try running the above commands again.
Remove-AzureRmAccount
Connect-AzureRmAccount
$context = Get-AzureRmContext


Once the above commands are properly executed, you can run the deployment script without any issues.
Refer Github issue for the relevant information.
